# google apps script sidebar form Send button not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a google add on for sheets. The sidebar I'm working on is intended to be sort of help ticket submission, but way before I can develop that part of things, I'm not getting the submit button in the form to call the javascript function I want to build.

I've removed all of the form data from the html button call to activate a Logger.log. No dice.
I created a completely separate (and very simple) button to call a different function to call Logger.log. This also did not work.
I've double checked the form data, the send call, and the function.
I made sure the name of the function (sendMsg) is unique.
I think that the issue may not be in my code but in some other way the html and javascript (.gs) are connected.

here is the html form:

```
<div class="block form-group">
<form>
  <label for="reason">Purpose of Contact</label>
  <select id="reason">
    <option selected>Help Request</option>
    <option>Feature Request</option>
    <option>Error Report</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" style="width: 200px;">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone" style="width: 120px;" value = "optional">
<br>
    <label for="translated-text">
      <b>Message</b></label>
    <textarea id="userMsg" rows="15" cols="35">
    </textarea>
<br>
<input id="app" name="appSrc" type="hidden" value="COE">
<input type="button" class="action" name="helpRequest" value="SEND" onClick="google.script.run.sendMsg( 
           document.getElementById('reason').value,
           document.getElementById('email').value,
           document.getElementById('phone').value,
           document.getElementById('userMsg').value,
           document.getElementById('appSrc').value
   )" />
   </form>
   </div>
```

and here is the function called:

```
function sendMsg(appSrc,reason,email,phone,userMsg) {
    appV = appSrc;
    reasonV = reason;
    emailV = email;
    phoneV = phone;
    userMsgV = userMsg;
    Logger.log('cheese');
}
```

Right now the form should simply result in a Logger.log message. At this point nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it was something simple. I now get the Logger.log feedback that will allow me to move forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In your situation, when "SEND" button is clicked, the script of `sendMsg()` at Google Apps Script side doesn't work.

  - You want to run `sendMsg()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- When I saw `<input id="app" name="appSrc" type="hidden" value="COE">`, `appSrc` is not id. By this, an error occurs at `document.getElementById('appSrc').value`, and `sendMsg()` didn't work. So if your script is modified, for example, please use `app`.

#### From:

```
document.getElementById('appSrc').value
```

#### To:

```
document.getElementById('app').value
```

Or

#### From:

```
<input id="app" name="appSrc" type="hidden" value="COE">
```

#### To:

```
<input id="appSrc" name="appSrc" type="hidden" value="COE">
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same issue as I had... `onpress` doesn't seem to work here. I had to change it to `onclick`.